# Linkedin Desktop application using Linkedin-j?

Tags: java, api, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn-j api for making a Linkedin application.The problem that I am facing is that I want to develop a simple desktop application. Rather I must say a console application. The problem comes where I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: api.linkedin.com
    at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:159)
    at com.lineedapp.common.LinkedinApp.main(LinkedinApp.java:17)
Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: api.linkedin.com
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
    at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:148)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.linkedin.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider.sendRequest(DefaultOAuthProvider.java:48)
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:177)
    ... 3 more
```

I suppose I am not able to provide a host in the application registration form. I did Provide Local host but its not working. Please Help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.linkedin.com
```

It looks like you don't have network access to `api.linkedin.com`. Make sure that, if you are behind a proxy or not, you have access to `https://api.linkedin.com`.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.net.UnknownHostException: api.linkedin.com` means that you are not able to reach the server.

Check that your are not behind a proxy. If so, you have to find a way to bypass this proxy in the linkedin API.

Comment: Ok ... I got it. I do enter a username and password for browsing ... tat means I am behind a proxy coz  I am in A specified domain. Can u tell me some java code through which I can bypass it??